# How can I resolve magic rectangle?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

Good day

I have a problem, I need to solve a "magic rectangle" similar tu "magic square" where the sum of upper and lower row its equal to 22, and the first and last column are 22 too. I can choose {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11}

The rectangle have 2 space blocked, the central ones.

_| _| _| _|

_| X| X| _|

_| _| _| _|

Please help me

Comment: All of the entries have to be distinct?

Comment: Yes... all need to be distinct

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
6&3&2&11\\
\hline
7&X&X&10\\
\hline
9&4&8&1\\
\hline
\end{array}